# angular 6 material design accordion openall

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-6

I tried to have two accordions group with different data in my angular application like the code which i have mentioned below but I don't know how to use two same components in my app.

```js
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, ViewChild, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {MatAccordion} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-demo-accordion',
  templateUrl: './demo-accordion.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./demo-accordion.component.css']
})
export class DemoAccordionComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  @ViewChild(MatAccordion) accordion: MatAccordion;
  @ViewChild(MatAccordion) testing: MatAccordion;
  displayMode: string = 'default';
  displayMode1: string = 'default';
  multi = true;
  hideToggle = false;
  hideToggle1 = false;
  disabled = false;
  showPanel3 = true;
  panel11 = false;
  expandedHeight: string;
  collapsedHeight: string;
}
```

```html
<h1>matAccordion</h1>
<div>
  <p>Accordion Options</p>
  <p>Accordion Actions <sup>('Multi Expansion' mode only)</sup></p>
  <div>
    <button mat-button (click)="accordion.openAll()" >Expand All</button>
    <button mat-button (click)="accordion.closeAll()" >Collapse All</button>
  </div>
  <p>Accordion Panel(s)</p>
</div>
<br>
<mat-accordion [displayMode]="displayMode" [multi]="multi" id="newcha"
              class="mat-expansion-demo-width">
  <mat-expansion-panel #panel1  [hideToggle]="hideToggle">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>Section 1</mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>This is the content text that makes sense here.</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel #panel2 [hideToggle]="hideToggle" [disabled]="disabled">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>Section 2</mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>This is the content text that makes sense here.</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
<br>
<hr>
<div>
<mat-accordion [displayMode]="displayMode1" [multi]="multi" id="testing"
              class="mat-expansion-demo-width">
  <mat-expansion-panel #panel11  [hideToggle]="hideToggle1">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>Section 12</mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>This is the content text that makes sense here.</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel #panel11 [hideToggle]="hideToggle1" [disabled]="disabled">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>Section 13</mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>This is the content text that makes sense here.</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
</div>
<div>
    <button mat-button (click)="testing.openAll()" >Expand All New</button>
    <button mat-button (click)="testing.closeAll()" >Collapse All New</button>
</div>
```

Now if i try to click the Expand All New Button it have to do the openAll for 2nd Accordion but it is opening the 1st Accordion
How to access the specific accordion in Angular Material Design? Like if i have two accordions with which parameter i can access the specific accordions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make a few minor changes to get this working.

Change:

```
@ViewChild(MatAccordion) accordion: MatAccordion;
@ViewChild(MatAccordion) testing: MatAccordion;
```

to:

```
@ViewChild('firstAccordion') firstAccordion: MatAccordion;
@ViewChild('secondAccordion') secondAccordion: MatAccordion;
```

Add in some functions:

```
openAllFirst() {
    this.firstAccordion.openAll();
}
closeAllFirst() {
    this.firstAccordion.closeAll();
}
openAllSecond() {
    this.secondAccordion.openAll();
}
closeAllSecond() {
    this.secondAccordion.closeAll();
}
```

And in the HTML, add the following to the two accordions:

```
<mat-accordion ....  #firstAccordion="matAccordion">
<mat-accordion ....  #secondAccordion="matAccordion">
```

And change the buttons to the new functions:

```
(click)="openAllFirst()"
```

I've copied your code above into Stackblitz, and made these changes.

[Stackblitz - Multiple accordion expand all](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zncjqi)

Comment: This worked for me, but why does this function differently than other angular components.  Why do we need this #firstAccordion="matAccordion"?

Answer (score 3):

Try property `expanded`

`[expanded]="true"`

For all expansion panel

Reference ---> https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/examples

Comment: Hi, Thank you for this, but my question is i need to use two <mat-accordion> and I have to control each accordions panel expansion and collapse by button clicks. Exactly like mentioned in the above HTML. By using @ViewChild i tried to access the mat-accordion but i can't able to access the second accordion. Only the 1st accordion is able to control on button click.

Comment: I keep getting this error: 

Can't bind to 'expanded' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-accordion'.